# ¿Como cargar archivos en carpetas nuevas dentro de /app/ en RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Como dice la pregunta, pues soy algo nuevo en RoR y me veo en la necesidad de crear nuevas carpetas como `root/app/helpers` o `root/app/extensions` en rails.

Cuando están carpetas las creo normal con el VSCode agrego nuevo archivo `root/app/helpers/my_helper.rb`

y su contenido es:

```
class MyHelper
    def self.llamar()
        puts "Si, estas en mi helper!"
    end
end
```

Cuanto este lo llamo desde un controlador o desde console `MyHelper.llamar()` me sale `NameError: uninitialized constant MyHelper` entonces no sé como cargar automaticamente el archivo personalizado en carpeta creada por mi dentro de app.

Answer (score 0):

En general la carpeta `helpers` es una carpeta especial que es solo invocable desde las vistas. Para hacerlo desde el controlador en el caso que mencionas, deberías llamar el método a través de:

```
helpers.llamar
```